# Post XML form using httr

Tags: xml, r, rcurl, httr

I am trying to POST an xml object using httr

In my application, I am creating the XML object like this:

```
  doc <- htmlTreeParse(conts, useInternalNodes = T)
  xmlFormula <- xpathSApply(doc, "//*/textarea", xmlValue)
  x <- xmlParseString(xmlFormula)
```

Then I modify the xml on the fly

and now want to post it using httr without saving it to disk and uploading from a file

```
  POST(MYURL, body=x) # this won't work
```

Is there a method to make the xml object httr friendly?

Comment: And by "wont work", what do you mean exactly? Can you actually create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You can try `POST(MYURL, body=saveXML(x))` however it is hard to help with out a reproducible example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: By not work, I mean I got Access denied error. I now replaced httr by postForm and it went through: `postForm(url, "xml"=saveXML(x), curl=curlobj, style="post")` worked. I guess I need to figure out how to do this with httr.